# Getting minimum order amount value of shipping method in shipping.html magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3.2

I want to display minimum order amount in custom shipping method in checkout and cart page.

These are the exact files i use for it. The minimum order amount is stored in core_config_data.
How to do it.Which files i have to edit for that? can you show me an example code.

app\code\Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html

app\code\Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\web\template\cart\shipping-rates.html

anybody pls help.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be so easy. I am assuming that you have already created the skeleton for your module.

First, you have to create a processor to set up the value from the config (Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_processor_name" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\ShippingProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Secondly, you have to create the processor class (Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\ShippingProcessor.php):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class ShippingProcessor implements LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    private $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * @param Config $config
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config $config,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function process($jsLayout): array
    {
        // this path you can verify on checkout_index_index.xml file
        $path = 'components/checkout/children/steps/children/shipping-step/children/shippingAddress';
        if ($this->arrayManager->get($path, $jsLayout)) {

            $jsLayout = $this->arrayManager->merge(
                $path,
                $jsLayout,
                [
                      'config' => ['template' => 'Vendor_Module/shipping'], 
                      'customValue' => $config->getCustomValue()
                ]
            );
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Thirdly, you must create the class responsible for loading the config

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Config
{
    private const XML_PATH_CUSTOM_VALUE = 'vendor_module/section/custom_value';

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomValue(): string
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_CUSTOM_VALUE);
    }
}
```

If you see on processor class I included a new path for the template, that will overwrite the default path of the shipping component Magento_Checkout/shipping by Vendor_Module/shipping, that is your HTML file. You must put it on Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

Finally, you can copy and past the content of the file: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html to your file and then include the content from customValue variable by adding this:

```
<div data-bind="html: customValue"></div>
```

Please let me know if it helps you of if you need something else.